# Проблема с выборкой MySQL JOIN

Tags: phpmyadmin, mysql

Здравствуйте, есть таблицы kvartira, domkat, garage, commercial, zemelnyi, у каждой нужно вытащить city=$city, пробовал так, но без результата:

```
"SELECT id, title, mini_img, text, price, adress FROM kvartira JOIN domkat JOIN garage JOIN commercial JOIN zemelnyi ON city = '$cityS' "
```

Comment: Пожалуйста не смейтесь, это мой первый такой массовый запрос)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эко вы клево приджойнили 5 таблиц.

[JOIN](http://www.webextends.net/articles/9-mysql/8-mysql-join.html) служит не для этого, вам нужно просто объеденить воедино 5 запросов ,оператор [UNION](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/union.html)

```
(SELECT id, title, mini_img, text, price, adress FROM kvartira WHERE city = '$cityS')
 UNION
(SELECT id, title, mini_img, text, price, adress FROM kvartira WHERE city = '$cityS')
 UNION
(SELECT id, title, mini_img, text, price, adress FROM domkat WHERE city = '$cityS')
 UNION
(SELECT id, title, mini_img, text, price, adress FROM garage WHERE city = '$cityS')
 UNION
(SELECT id, title, mini_img, text, price, adress FROM commercial WHERE city = '$cityS')
 UNION
(SELECT id, title, mini_img, text, price, adress FROM zemelnyi WHERE city = '$cityS')
```

Кстати рискну спросить, зачем вам 5 одинаковых таблиц? Может все слить в одну и добавить поле type, куда и писать kvartira, domkat, garage, commercial, zemelnyi

Comment: )))  спасибо)

Comment: Они все не одинаковые, ну есть у них похожие, вы не поможете мне подключить ваш код себе, а то я подключил ощибку дает